# Issues running image recognition code with mrcnn, tensorflow, and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on setting up an image recognition code and I have run into a few issues.  I have a 3080 and I am trying to get it to work with my code.  I currently am using:

tensorflow==1.15

Keras==2.2.4

mrcnn==0.2

I have CUDA 10.0 installed with the CUDA toolkit and when my code runs it successfully imports all libraries:

```
2021-02-02 18:57:57.027322: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.210157: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.409046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.435022: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.632331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.804898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_100.dll
2021-02-02 18:57:57.994055: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
```

When I use `nvidia-smi` in CMD it shows that the drivers are still set-up for CUDA 11.2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoprA.png)

In the end, it gets to my first EPOCH and stops for close to 20 min and gives me this error message:

```
Epoch 1/8
2021-02-02 19:01:47.774849: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2021-02-02 19:02:53.264434: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-02-02 19:15:45.683866: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2021-02-02 19:15:46.576524: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
2021-02-02 19:15:46.576720: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4963] [stream=0000019067309460,impl=000001907DA1B420] did not memzero GPU location; source: 000000046860DDE8
2021-02-02 19:15:46.576743: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_filter_ops.cc:1038 : Not found: No algorithm worked!
2021-02-02 19:15:46.576820: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:316] did not allocate timer: 000000046860DD90
2021-02-02 19:15:46.576933: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4976] [stream=0000019067309460,impl=000001907DA1B420] did not memset GPU location; source: 000000046822C6D8; size: 8388608; pattern: ffffffff
2021-02-02 19:15:46.577177: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4976] [stream=0000019067309460,impl=000001907DA1B420] did not memset GPU location; source: 000000046822C6F8; size: 8388608; pattern: ffffffff
2021-02-02 19:15:46.577081: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1964] [stream=0000019067309460,impl=000001907DA1B420] did not enqueue 'start timer': 000000046860DD90
2021-02-02 19:15:46.577481: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1976] [stream=0000019067309460,impl=000001907DA1B420] did not enqueue 'stop timer': 000000046860DD90
2021-02-02 19:15:46.577564: F tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/gpu_timer.cc:65] Check failed: start_event_ != nullptr && stop_event_ != nullptr 
2021-02-02 19:15:46.577550: I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream
```

I am not sure where to go from here I have tried a number of different methods for others that had this issue and I cannot get anything to work.  If there is anyone who knows what I can do or any ways to get this to work.

Comment: CUDA 10 and the version of Tensorflow you have doesn't have support for your GPU built in. You will need to upgrade to a version of Tensorflow which supports CUDA 11 and install that

Comment: run it on colab, i think that it will be more better to avoid versioning problems

Comment: is there any way to get mrcnn to work with the newer versions of TensorFlow and Keras?

Comment: If you have added any callback function, try once without callback functions.

Comment: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED means the program failed to execute on GPU. This is due to the launch failure of the kernel on the GPU. I am assuming you are using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080. For this GPU card, support starts from CUDA 11.x. Once you upgrade Tensorflow >= TF2.4, will resolve your issue. Thanks!